# getline() съедает первый символ строки при чтении из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, io

Проблема следующая, нужно считать несколько строк из файла и вывести. Начиная со второй, нумеровать. Для этого сделал счетчик и его проверку. Но не в этом суть. `getline()` обрезает первый символ в строках, начиная со второй. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Пример:
Файл на вход содержит:

```
First
Second
Third
```

Текст программы:
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include  // подключаем функции ввода-вывода
    #include  // подключаем функции чтения-записи в файл
    #include

```
using namespace std; // объявляем пространство имен

void Func(const char *filename)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char input;
    string line;
    ifstream a_1(filename, ios::in);
    if (a_1.is_open())
    {
        while (a_1 >> input)
        {
            getline(a_1, line);         
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                cout << line << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << counter << " " << line << "\n";
            }
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Func("data.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так вы же считываете его в

```
while(a_1 >> input)
```

Что ж удивительного, что в `line` строка без того символа, что в `input`?...

Проверяйте уж так:

```
while(getline(a_1, line))
{
    ...
```

Вот полный текст, чтоб не было вопросов:

```
#include <iostream> // подключаем функции ввода-вывода
#include <fstream> // подключаем функции чтения-записи в файл
#include <string>

using namespace std; // объявляем пространство имен

void Func(const char *filename)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream a_1(filename, ios::in);
    if (a_1.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(a_1, line))
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                cout << line << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << counter << " " << line << "\n";
            }
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Func("data.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот data.txt

```
First
Second
Third
```

Вот вывод

```
First
1 Second
2 Third
```

теперь получилось?

Comment: Спасибо, а как тогда проверить, что он не закончился?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: В таком случае игнорируется первая строка полностью.

Comment: Вы случайно не оставили `getline` еще и в теле цикла? :) Уберите его оттуда, вы уже считали строку в заголовке! У меня все корректно работает.

Comment: data.txt в столбик.

Comment: так и есть, спасибо еще раз)